# How to find reoccuring string groups (order does not matter) in a dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

There are fixed number of strings that are repeated in the dictionary lists: String items -- `Ruth, James, Sandy, Daniel, Sarah, Tommy, Alex, Rob, Teddy, Steve, Mark`. Here `n = 11`.

My dictionary looks like the following (number after the key is rank of groups):

```
DictionaryLists = {
                   1: {1 : ['Teddy', 'Daniel', 'Alex']},
                   2: {2 : ['Rob', 'Steve', 'Mark', 'Sandy']},
                   3: {5 : ['Ruth', 'Sarah', 'James']},
                   4: {1 : ['Teddy', 'Alex', 'Steve', 'Sandy', 'Daniel']},
                   5: {2 : ['Mark', 'Sarah', 'Rob']},
                   6: {1 : ['Teddy', 'Daniel', 'Alex']},
                   7: {2 : ['Mark', 'Sandy']}
                  }
```

**Task 1: What I want to find:**
I want to find out the frequency of combination of string items list (order does not matter). Let's say if I pick a combination of `Teddy, Daniel, Alex` (order does not matter) then I want to see the frequency of this group when rank = 1. Then I want to see what are the strings that are in rank = 2 WHEN `Teddy, Daniel, Alex` is in rank = 1. For example, `Rob` is in the rank 2 when those three names are in rank 1. `Teddy, Alex, Daniel` group appears 3 times in rank 1. `Rob` appears two times. So the result should be,

```
Teddy,Daniel,Alex,3,Rob,2
```

It means `Teddy,Daniel,Alex` appears three times in rank = 1: and `Rob` appears 2 times in rank = 2 when those three names are in rank = 1.

My try:
I created a list with all the lists in the dictionary. `TotalLists = [OneGroupRank1, OneGroupRank2, OneGroupRank3, TwoGroupRank1, TwoGroupRank2, ThreeGroupRank1, ThreeGroupRank2]`.

```
n=3
NewDict = {}
TotalListStrings = tuple(TotalLists[0][0:n]) #3 strings are taken from the list 0 
NewDict = {TotalListStrings : 1}
for IndividualLists in lists[1:]:
    if all(item in IndividualList for item in TotalListStrings):
        NewDict[TotalListStrings]+=1
print(NewDict)
```

This basically takes three strings from the 0th list and finds patterns. This produced the result of `{(String1, String2, String3):9}` --> 9 is the number of occurrences.

My questions are:

(1) How can I check patterns in the dictionary when there are conditions to check (checking key values and then proceeding) for each group?

(2) How can I create a combination of all names (n=11) as a group of 3 and check for patterns? Instead of relying on the lists, I simply want to create combination of three names. For example, Teddy, Daniel, Alex another one would be Teddy, Rob, Steve, etc.

(3) How can the **Task 1** mentioned above can be accomplished?

Comment: This question does not really explain the task you are trying to accomplish very clearly; I suspect an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Where are these dictionaries coming from? What is the overall goal? What (if anything) is the significance of the keys in `DictionaryLists` (and why isn't there a `7`)? I can answer question 2 ([`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)) and if order doesn't matter look at [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am sorry. I stated my overall goal in Task 1.

Comment: Yes, I read that, but could you explain the bigger picture - why do you think you need to accomplish Task 1?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am performing associative rule mining. I just want to see if a certain group is in the rank 1, which strings are most likely to follow. For example, I will pick a group (say A,B,C) through itertools.combinations and then I will check when A,B,C are in rank 1 for the total of 10 times, then C, D are 8 times in rank 2. Is it clear? Please let me know and I can explain further.

Comment: Not totally clear (to me, at least). What do the ranks mean? How do you know which rank 2s correspond to which rank 1s (if its just consecutive keys, consider a better structure, e.g. `{dataset: {rank: set(members)}}`). Should `Mark` and `3` be an output too? Is there a particular output format you need (the current one doesn't make sense)? Also, what exactly do you mean by *"conditions to check"*? Perhaps you could cut this down to separate questions with tighter scopes?

Comment: @jonrsharpe There is not particular output format. Cutting down is a good idea, but I was afraid people might loose the chain of the logic. Ranks are preassigned to each group. You are right, that is how I structured it. 1 (dataset) : 1 (rank) : ['A', 'B', 'C'] (members). Yes, If a name is in 2nd rank then that name should be compared with the group that we are checking. How many times the name Mark occurs in rank 2 when, say, A,B,C is in rank 1.

Comment: So an input would be three names to look for in rank 1, and an output would be a dictionary `{name: appearances}` (where `appearances` is the number of times that name is at rank 2 where all input names are in rank 1)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58188/discussion-between-gravity-m-and-jonrsharpe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming (what I think is) a more sensible input format:

```
data = {'A': {1: ['Teddy', 'Daniel', 'Alex'],
              2: ['Rob', 'Steve', 'Mark', 'Sandy'],
              3: ['Ruth', 'Sarah', 'James']},
        'B': {1: ['Teddy', 'Alex', 'Steve', 'Sandy', 'Daniel'],
              2: ['Mark', 'Sarah', 'Rob']},
        'C': {1: ['Teddy', 'Daniel', 'Alex'], 
              2: ['Mark', 'Sandy']}}
```

You could do this like:

```
from collections import Counter

output = {1: 0, 2: Counter()}

names = frozenset(['Teddy', 'Daniel', 'Alex'])

for dataset in data.values():
    if names.issubset(dataset[1]):
        output[1] += 1
        output[2].update(dataset[2])
```

Which would give the output:

```
>>> output
{1: 3, 
 2: Counter({'Mark': 3, 
             'Rob': 2, 
             'Sandy': 2, 
             'Sarah': 1, 
             'Steve': 1})}
```

By making `names` a `frozenset`, it can also be used as a dictionary key, so you can run through all `combinations` and get the eventual output:

```
{names: {1: "count at rank 1", 2: "Counter for rank 2"}}
```

You can also extend this to higher ranks, where available.

Comment: great answer. Exactly what i m looking for. But how to make names = frozenset(['Teddy', 'Daniel', 'Alex']), the name combinations to be automatic? and assign it to a dictionary ?

Comment: That bit you can do for yourself - again, look at [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), which will generate 3-tuples of names.

Comment: just a quick question. Can I do it by replacing A, B, C with 1, 2, 3. When I run it it with 1, 2, 3, it shows me key error in      if names.issubset(dataset[1]):

Comment: @GravityM that shouldn't make a difference; the outer key isn't used in my code.